# Can't run shell_exec(.php) with mysql in php script

Tags: php

**Different from the other situations I found here on SO**

I have the following code in the main php script

```
include("sql.php"); //holds all the data to mysql (and variable $db to connect)

$output = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/php folder/another_script.php')
```

and in ***another_script.php*** I have this:

```
include_once("../sql.php"); //notice difference to previous include in the other script

$query = "some query";
$db->query($query)
```

**$output** in the first script is blank. The second script runs when alone and not called from another script. What am I missing?

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: @BartFriederichs for some reason, I'm sure, else I wouldn't be asking... That's not important. The point is I am asking why this won't work this way. I don't want to run it by a different code structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) says:

> Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string

It returns the output. You never use the output, hence nothing is shown. You could do this:

```
$output = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/php folder/another_script.php')
echo $output;
```

Yet, I advise you to reconsider your design to create classes or functions to separate functionality instead of calling (quite expensive) shells to call PHP code.

Comment: I echo the output. Nothing is shown. This is called as soon as my server starts. No problem in performance.

Comment: none. I only get an error when I change the path and get "could not open/find file xxx/another_script.php". Since I get nothing like this I'm assuming it is correct...

Comment: so, no idea? I really can't figure it out at all, do you think of anything that might be off? :)